# Custom token not being replaced

Tags: tokens, 9

In my_module I have the following:

```
function my_module_token_info()
{
  $info = [];
  $info['types']['my_module_tokens'] = [
      'name' => 'My Module Tokens',
      'description' => t('Tokens specific to my module.'),
  ];
  $info['tokens']['my_module_tokens']['my_token'][] = 'For my token in a node body';

  return $info;
}

function my_module_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data, array $options, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) {
  $replacements = [];

  if ($type == 'my_module_tokens') {
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'my_token':
          $replacements[$original] = 'test';
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  return $replacements;
}
```

In a node body I have [my_module_tokens:my_token]

Now, the token info is found and processed, and appears in the token list. The implementation of hook_tokens does not fire unless I add the following:

```
function my_module_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $token = Drupal::token();
  $token->replace("[my_module_tokens:my_token]", array('node'=>$variables['node']), array('clear' => TRUE));
  }
}
```

The token information and replacement text are sent off to the tokens logic, but the result is that the token in the body text is unchanged.

Comment: Does your token work in other places, like a url pattern? I.e. is it only not working in your body field? Do other tokens work in the body field?

Comment: I'm not using the token anywhere else. It's meant (once it's firing and I add the rest of the logic) to insert an AdSense in-content ad.
But getting the answer to your second question surprised me. I used the core token [user:mail] just below the other, and it also is not replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a way to process the token. The [Token Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) module provides a ckeditor filter plugin to do this when the field is rendered.

From the module's README:

> Install the module as any other module. Visit the text format administration
> page at /admin/config/content/formats/filters and edit a text format. Check the
> 'Replaces global tokens with their value' filter and save the text format.

> When editing a form where this text format is used in a field, you can type
> global tokens that will be replaced when the field is rendered.

Answer (score -2):

Ah, got it. I had my brain in backwards. Token replacement is on node save, not when it's rendered. Calling token replace in hook_node_presave did it.

Comment: I think you probably want to use a ckeditor filter plugin for this.

Comment: Sure, could, but I’d still have to write the logic that does the replacement of the token with text. Ckeditor would mostly just give me the dropping in of the token via a button.

Comment: If you process the token in a presave, you'll actually store the processed value in the database. Imo, this defeats the point of a token.

Comment: Could go either way. It really depends on the specific token, whether it is just to save looking something up or a few keystrokes and isn’t likely to ever change, so that doing the replacement before ever render is a waste, or whether it makes sense to do so because it’s replacement is in any way needing a current dynamic value. Good point. I’ll put your comment as an answer and I’ll pick it instead, as most often it would apply even if not in this case.

Comment: PS I think the down vote on the question was unnecessary. Wanting to know how to accomplish something via native Drupal without using a contrib module isn’t a bad thing. Contrib modules come and expire, while the business case remains.

Comment: Fwiw, I think the down votes are because your question lacks some basic debugging steps. E.g. my first questions. Not because it's not a question worth asking/answering.